# Get repeated key => values in every array within a multiarray + other no repeated key = > values

Tags: php

i have this multi array "$marray wich has inside some array with some similar key = value and some not look like this :

```
$marray = array(
 array("id" => "1", "be_pro" => 6, "name" => "a1", "service" => 4a),
 array("id" => "2", "be_pro" => 6, "name" => "a1", "service" => 4d),
 array("id" => "3", "be_pro" => 4, "name" => "a4", "service" => 3d),
 array("id" => "4", "be_pro" => 4, "name" => "a4", "service" => 3s),
 array("id" => "6", "be_pro" => 4, "name" => "a4", "service" => 34),
 array("id" => "8", "be_pro" => 3, "name" => "a3", "service" => 4r),
 array("id" => "8", "be_pro" => 3, "name" => "a3", "service" => 4d)
);
```

So i would like to get new arrays with "id", "be_pro" and "name" once then "service" plus "service" from next array till "be_pro" in the new array is different , so if is different put in the next array.

How should i do this?

what i need is print a multi array and within and array with every row with similar be_pro

Comment: you should probably brush up your basic php syntax :) just saying

Comment: you should re-implement this one. Just 1 6 a1 4a 4d 3 4 a4 3d 3s 34 8 3 a3 4r 4d should be in array, then you would implode() them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This help me:

```
  // first get all bepro_id and put in array
   foreach($all_rows as $service){
    $bepros[$service['bepro_id']]++;
   }
  //var_dump($bepros);

 //Then for each be pro_id print every row , so print every service , then for be pro_id,id,name just print the first key "[0]" the array inside $new_array

 foreach ($bepros as $key=>$bepro){
    if(isset($new_bep)){
        $x = 0 + $new_bep;
    }else{
        $x = 0;
    }
    $new_array[] = array_slice($all_rows,$x,$bepro);

    // get where let before
    $new_bep=$x + $bepro;
 }
```